# Are there any benefits to using a slideshow for content

Tags: website-design, usability, content, slideshow

[I don't often go to answers.com, but when I do, I just really wonder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u811U.png)... why are their answers presented in a slideshow format? [Here is an example](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_are_all_questions_answered_in_a_slideshow) of one such question. What I'd like to know is if there are any benefits to doing this at all. I personally find it really annoying when I'm looking for an answer to a pointless question to have to click for every 5th word I want to read.

I'd also like to know, what would be the motivation behind doing this? I honestly can't think of any professional site ever doing this.

**PS:** after checking this in other browsers, for some reason the answers only seem to be in a slideshow when viewed using Google Chrome.

**PPS:** Example image: [image: Example of the slideshow view] This image shows how little of the answer is shown. The next slide does actually say "$$$. I think there's an option to disable the slideshow and go to simple text.", so answers are just cut in half between slides. A slide takes up about 15 words, and then you have to click to see the rest of that sentence.

Comment: I just found the button that said something like 'this is a beta page; click here to return to the normal view', and now I can't return to the slideshow view anymore. I tried changing `?classic=true` (which the button sent me to) to `?classic=false`, clearing my cookies, using Chrome Canary, but nothing worked. I'm starting to get the impression this is all some kind of cruel joke or something. What's going on?

Comment: Hm, I don’t see any slideshow. (If there’s something like that, it would explain why I’ve never seen more than one answer on answers.com yet ^^)

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't see the slideshow either - think you must have triggered some sort of user configuration view on the website somehow.

Comment: I've been on that site a ton of times following links on search pages, and today is the first day that I have seen that behaviour, which is, as they mention, on a beta state. So we can expect that to be the default way in some time, but for now, it's not. I have to mention that the design they have right now is also not very good, not too bad either, but not very good. I feel the site full of noise.

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit I can think of is that it gives an unique experience. Setting it apart from other Q/A websites.